# xf86EnableIO failed to enable I/O when starting X server

Tags: 22.04, xorg, xserver

Running `sudo startx` on Ubuntu 22.04/Gnome 42.5 with X11 windowing system results in the following terminal output:

```
X.Org X Server 1.21.1.4
X Protocol Version 11, Revision 0
Current Operating System: Linux patrick-desktop 5.19.0-41-generic #42~22.04.1-Ubuntu SMP PREEMPT_DYNAMIC Tue Apr 18 17:40:00 UTC 2 x86_64
Kernel command line: BOOT_IMAGE=/boot/vmlinuz-5.19.0-41-generic root=UUID=aa0796c0-4f0d-412e-a9bf-a812770917ff ro quiet splash vt.handoff=7
xorg-server 2:21.1.4-2ubuntu1.7~22.04.1 (For technical support please see http://www.ubuntu.com/support) 
Current version of pixman: 0.40.0
    Before reporting problems, check http://wiki.x.org
    to make sure that you have the latest version.
Markers: (--) probed, (**) from config file, (==) default setting,
    (++) from command line, (!!) notice, (II) informational,
    (WW) warning, (EE) error, (NI) not implemented, (??) unknown.
(==) Log file: "/var/log/Xorg.0.log", Time: Sat May  6 12:37:21 2023
(==) Using system config directory "/usr/share/X11/xorg.conf.d"
xf86EnableIO: failed to enable I/O ports 0000-03ff (Operation not permitted)
xinit: connection to X server lost

waiting for X server to shut down (II) Server terminated successfully (0). Closing log file.
```

What is causing this error, and how can I get it working?